# com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]

Tags: android

I delete my old fire-base project and create a new project.
after that I got this error.

First The error was sha 1 that why I delete the old project and create new one.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;


private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    startActivityForResult(
            // Get an instance of AuthUI based on the default app
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build(),
                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
                    ))
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(!BuildConfig.DEBUG /* credentials */, true /* hints */)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN);
 }

}
```

**This is very simple code no error is there. It was work before.**

I think the problem is somewhere technical. like somewhere in fire-base console.

[image: Probem Screenshot]

Comment: did u change your google-services.json ?

Comment: Yes I did. But Its small like its come from this JSON. I Download and replace it didn't work. I sink it with my project it didn't work ether.

Comment: well i think you have to enable the auth provider you are using in auth section of your firebase console

Comment: @HarKal Let me try.

Comment: @HarKal I enable It . No Issue is there.

Comment: could you show the whole logs please ?

Comment: @HarKal Wait a Sec.

Comment: @HarKa Please See the screen Shot.
 https://snipboard.io/YWgtlx.jpg
Is it helpfull.

Comment: i ll say it again. it has something to do with api credentials in that google-services.json file. you can try one more thing go to the firebase console and check if there is some activity in the app

Comment: @HarKa Let Me see again.

Comment: @HarKa dear I downlod the JSON and compare it and It look like similar to me. https://snipboard.io/2TfdhK.jpg

Comment: did u check app activity in firebase console. is there any kind of activity in firebase console? does it show your app online ?

Comment: @HarKa Let me see.

Comment: @HarKa Last 30 minits I am in this page.
  https://snipboard.io/QKF2wT.jpg

Comment: @HarKa I find no activity.

Comment: reomove that google json file from app and then delete app from firebase console after that create new app in console and then dont close the process until your app shows online in app integration page in console. it would be better if u also submit tha SHA1 certificate in optional field

Comment: @HarKal I got new error after creating the project :

an internal error has occurred [api key not valid please press a valid api key]

this happened when I run y apps in emulater and try to open a account using a phonenumber.

Comment: @HarKal I partially solve it and I am not satisfied with it. It works on my device but not working in the emulator.
Another thing, base on this local work I publish a new release but google still not publish those release so I am waiting for seeing the new release. Most of my equipment is still give me errors.

Comment: please update your certificate in google play console

Comment: and phone auth doesnt work on emulators.read the docs

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I was also facing this issue.

Solution:
change the version of google services at project level gradle and sync your project and reinstall.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Comment: This is right solution. I was facing same issue with google play service version 4.3.5 but after changing google play service version from 4.3.6 to 4.3.0 My issue got resolved. Big Thanks.

Comment: thanks for solution...u saved the whole... in addition i also overwrite the googleServices.json file...

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my final degree project. I'm 2 days away from delivering it, I had everything perfect but I failed the login and got frustrated. Thanks a lot

Comment: thanks a lot buddy, i was just wondering i did you figured this out ?

Answer (score 37):

What worked for me was going to "Build" -> "Clean Project" and running it.

(I also tried syncing Firebase on Android Studio, recreated google-services.json, but none actually worked for me until cleaning the project)

Comment: You Stell Facing it.

Comment: No no, i have solved it doing what is said on this answer. Cleaning the project helped me

Comment: Doing a clean build fixes everything sometimes. Thanks for saving me a lot of hair-pulling. :D

Comment: it is not your answer alone but a combination of many answers that helped me

Comment: I've tested and confirm the solution to clean project will be more correct than downgrading google-services version.

Answer (score 10):

Your API key from your Firebase must match with the Key of your google-services.json file to solve this issue, check the image here
[check image from android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XndTZ.png)

[check image from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obUeD.png)

After doing this, Goto your android studio click **Tools** > **AVD Manager** > Choose your emulator and **Wipe Data** Now run the app again

Comment: Great. I am facing same issue I just download google services json file again and set in my application and issue disappear.
thanks!.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to E.Akio I also needed to clean and then rebuild.
However in VSCode I see no menu option for clean so from command line:

> cd android
>   .\gradlew.bat clean

Then I launched the app again with F5 and the new google-services.json must have been incuded in the build because the error disappeared.

Comment: This is the right solution for VSCode users. if you are in windows:   ./gradlew.bat clean

Answer (score 2):

For Android:
Go to

> cd android

For Windows:

> gradlew.bat clean

Then close all the applications such as Emulator, Code Editor and build again. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I've tried a lot of solutions ,but all of them didn't work;
So I disconnected the app from firebase and removed it from my project in the firebase console ,then I connected it again using android studio assistant. This link shows how to disconnect your app from firebase : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-remove-firebase-authentication-in-android-studio/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have same issues
I deleted firebase project. and I made new project.
After I add new google service file, 'clean project' works well

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but it might help someone who did something ridiculous like me. The root of my problem is that i forgot to change the `google-services.json` file in app folder. All i did is change that file, then **clean project** and **rebuild project**. You can confirm that the configuration has changed by doing `ctrl + click` on `R.string.default_web_client_id`, this will lead you to `values.xml` which is generated under build folder.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was going to "Build" -> "Clean Project" and running it
this is not solution

please check your package name same on firebase and android studio

and than

close your android studio project and rerun your project

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue, It worked for me.

Redownload the google-services.json file and add it to the Project and change the classpath in Project Level Gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

Sync and run your project it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly restricted the google services JSON API key from my gcloud dashboard API dashboard to only maps on android, so i recommend checking any restriction from there.

Answer (score 0):

what helped me was:

1. cd .\android\  && ./gradlew clean (in Terminal)
2. delete phone and File -> invalidate cache / restart (in Android Studio), add new phone
3. close and open code editor

Answer (score 0):

Disable  Email/Password  in Firebase Authentication Sign-in providers
Download google-service.jason File manually
and past it in app folder
will fix your issue