# com.google.firebase.FirebaseException : An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login/register in my flutter app but it says the api key is invalid. It used worked fine earlier but after I ran **flutter clean** and **flutter pub get** subsequently , just couldnt login/register anymore.

[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TenfF.png)
The solutions that I tried were:

1. Tried to resolve the issue by creating a new firebase app, but that didn't help either
2. Uninstall the app and run again
3. Check the build.gradle in app level as well as project
   How do I fix it?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59016466/6322723

Comment: Try this one as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411803/6322723

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion , I already tried all of those and none of them worked for me