# com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]

Tags: flutter, firebase

The error is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654144/com-google-firebase-firebaseexception-an-internal-error-has-occurred-api-key), but in Flutter, not native Android, so I wanted to add this question.

I renamed my flutter project using the package `change_app_package_name` and since then the connection to my firebase backend didn't work anymore, when I tried to log a user in inside the app, the response from `firebase authentication` was:

```
com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key. ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I replaced and restricted the API keys in the google cloud console, the API keys are connected to your project name and I think you have to create new ones when renaming the project. Then I added a new project in the firebase console with the new package name and project name at `project settings` -> `my apps` and replaced the google-service.json in my flutter project
[image: project settings]

What is now easy to overlook is that you also have to change the lib/firebase-options.dart file:

```
 static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'AIz...', // <- this API Key was not correct anymore in my case!
    appId: '1:93...',
    messagingSenderId: '93...',
    projectId: 'gr...',
    storageBucket: 'gr....appspot.com',
  );
```

This apiKey needs to match the one in the firebase setting:
[image: firebase API Key]

Then it should work again. (tbh I don't 100% understood it, because there was a also a automatically generated API Key in my cloud console, I'm not sure how this happens, but the important part for me was to make sure that the API Key in `firebase-options.dart` and `google-service.json` matches to the one in the project settings page)